RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arcsin
I have the following code:
def f(x,y):
    t = np.where(x==0, 0, x/y)
    return np.where(abs(t)<=1, np.arcsin(t), np.NaN)

npts = 500
x = np.linspace(-10,10, npts)
y = np.linspace(-10,10, npts)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = f(x,y)

I am receiving the following

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arcsin

that I do not understand why. Can someone please help me?

The arguments to np.where are evaluated BEFORE they are passed to the function.  So the abs(t)<=1 test does not prevent arcsin from being evaluated for larger t.  This use of where will control the value you get back from the function, but won't silence the warning.

You could use the where and out parameters of np.arcsin instead

There are many questions about runtimewarning and np.where. I closed this with the best recent duplicate I could find.

The domain of a function is set of all possible input values for which the function is defined. The arcsin function (which is aka sine inverse function) has a domain of [-1,1]. This means that only values that are greater than (or equal to) -1 and lesser than (or equal to) 1 are permissible values to this function.
Just try to change the input variables to the linspace function of yours and the error can be resolved.
If you want some theoretical background, refer this.

The solution provided by Yaroslav works perfectly. Thanks to all for your time. Abdul

It is because you have values outside [-1,1].
The argument of np.arcsin() must be between -1 and 1. Giving values bigger than 1 and smaller than -1 results in NaN.

I could spot an error in your code:
t = np.where(x==0, 0, x/y)

should be y/x (or y==0).
The origin of the error is otherwise unclear (and I don't use numpy). However, I could fix that by doing the calculation in two steps:
u = np.where(abs(t)<=1, t, np.NaN)
return np.arcsin(u)


np.arcsin() is going to take values from -1 to 1. But you are giving values greater 1. in cases of your grid, you are dividing values of x-coordinates with values greater than x-coordinates with y-coordinates(ex:-9.4/-10 value is greater than 1).

I thought that -9.4/-10 is smaller than one. I also checked it in the interpreter, it says the same.
